# Strange C++ behavior. Value gets overriden

Tags: c++, scanf, undefined-behavior

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
int t;
scanf("%d",&t);
while(t--){
    long long int val;
    char op;
    scanf("%lld",&val);
    while(true){
        long long int x;
        scanf("%s",&op);
        if(op=='=')break;
        scanf("%lld",&x);
        cout<<"***"<<t<<endl;
        if(op=='+')val+=x;
        else if(op=='-')val-=x;
        else if(op=='*')val*=x;
        else val/=x;
    }
    printf("%lld",val);
 }
```

}

In the above code, I can't understand why the value of ***t*** is getting set to 0 after I am taking input in x. You can even print and check that t is bein set to zero. I have even checked it on ideone. http://ideone.com/JeCbSv
Any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `scanf` to read in `op` is invalid. `op` is a single `char`, so you should read with

```
scanf("%c",&op);
```

Not

```
scanf("%s",&op);
```

Comment: which is why it is safer to use `std::cin > op` instead. `<iostream>` has been included, after all.

Comment: @Nawaz but std::cin > op is slow

Comment: `cin >> op`, agreed. And it's not statistically significantly slower to read in a single character with `cin` than `scanf`. Maybe when you have thousands, yes.

Comment: @VikashKesarwani:  Are you *really* worrying about it?  Have you profiled your program? Is that `std::cin` that makes your program slow?

Comment: I am interested in knowing, <i>why\/i> this is happening?

Comment: @AdwaitKumar: It is basically Undefined Behavior, so theoretically *anything* could happen. The explanation cannot come from C (or C++). The generated machine code *might* have the explanation; if it doesn't, you're out of luck: you have to study the hardware/pipeline/etc for that.